# Setting the maxlength of a textbox to a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to set the `maxlength` value of a textbox to the length of a string using javascript, but the maxlength doesn't change at all.

```
<input name="answerTxt" type="text" class="form" id="answer" onkeypress="do_enter(event);" onkeyup="count('answer');" size="25" maxlength="5"> &nbsp; 
<script>
    var txt = "hello"
    document.getElementById('answer').maxlength = txt.length
</script>
```

Comment: What does `do_enter()` do?

Comment: It's [`maxLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#properties) (capital `L`), not `maxlength`. Voting to close as typo/non-repro.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not really. A comment told me to use setAttribute and I just tested it, and it worked, without the capital L.

Comment: There's a difference between accessing DOM element attributes via `.getAttribute()` and using properties exposed on DOM nodes. You can in fact set `.maxLength` directly on the node, and that will do the same thing as updating the attribute.

Comment: @779804 - See Pointy's comment. Attribute names aren't case-sensitive in HTML. Reflected properties **are** case-sensitive in the DOM. (And sometimes the name doesn't even match the property -- `className` vs. `class` and `htmlFor` vs. `for` being the most popular examples.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('answer').setAttribute("maxlength", txt.length)
```

You can use setAttribute() function instead. Or if you want to use maxlength property, you must write 'maxLength', not 'maxlength'.

```js
document.getElementById('answer').maxLength = txt.length
```

I hope you understand.